# Ansible import_playbook on directories or with regular expressions

Tags: ansible

Can Ansible directive import_playbook be used with regular expressions or simply on a directory?

What I want to do is something like:

```
- import_playbook: playbook*.yml
```

(to import in order or playbooks with name starting with playbook and with .yml extension)

or

```
- import_playbook: playbook-to-be-imported/*
```

Comment: what's the problem with trying it out by yourself?

Comment: `- import_playbook: playbook*.yml` does not work

Comment: you got your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The loop control section of the docs say that "In 2.0 you are again able to use with_loops and task includes (but not playbook includes)" (see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Technically you could do it the dirty way with: `command: ansible-playbook` but I would avoid that.

Try to use with_loops + tasks includes instead.